# Incorrect validation message on Identity 2.0 registration form

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

In the 2.0.0 release issue 2040 was marked as Closed and Fix.   When a user is registered and the email address already exists, the message returned is:

•Name [] is already taken.
•Email [] is already taken.

This should read Username [] is already taken to prevent confusion.

Will this be corrected or is there another way to address this.

p.s.  I have updated to 2.2.0-alpha1 and the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add correct error message checking the IdentityResults like below.

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors.Where(error => !error.StartsWith("Name")))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: My explanation code will return Email is already taken only. It is is ignoring "Name is already taken" section. You need to change the implementation to support your needs BTW.